# Partials and local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

If we want to pass a collection to partial, we do like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @posts %>
```

If we want to pass a single object within a custom variable, we do this:

```
<%= render :partial => "item", :locals => { :item => @advertisement } %>
```

Now what should I do to to pass a **collection**, "proxying" it through a custom variable (like the second case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass it through locals like in your second example

```
<%= render :partial => "item", :locals => { :posts => @posts } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the other way of calling partials:

```
render(:partial => 'post', :object => @posts)
```

Comment: My bad, it's actually :object, but the same thing applies.

It's in the RDoc documentation for Rails: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Answer (score 1):

I found using :as parameter much more clear:

```
<%= render :partial => "item", :collection => @rabbits, :as => :item %>
```